# UIDocumentPickerController doesn't show cancel button

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

For the app I am currently working on I want to open a `UIDocumentPickerController` as a full screen popover. It works great but when the app is in split screen and not in the compact horizontal size class or full screen the cancel button is no longer visible. I could so far not find anything on this issue but I can not be the only one to have it.

Has anyone a solution to this issue?

In 50/50 and 70/30 split screen the cancel button is not visible:
[image]
[image]

In a 30/70 split and full screen the cancel button is visible:
[image]
[image]

Edit: Fixed a typo

Comment: This happens on the iPhone too. You need to tap the Back button once or twice for the Cancel button to appear. There's nothing you can do in code to change this.

Comment: On iPhone you at least can get a cancel button but on iPad you are stuck for good. There there is not back until you see it. It is not reachable sadly.